# Does $\{\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega) \leq t\} =\{\omega \in \Omega: \delta(\omega) =1\}\cap \{\omega \in \Omega: T(\omega) \leq t\}$ hold?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $X,Y$ denote to absolutely continuous random variables (which need not be indepedent). Let $T:= \min{\{X,Y\}}$ and let $\delta = 1$ if $X \leq Y$ and $\delta=0$ otherwise.

My question is if:
$$\{\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega) \leq t\} \overset{?}{=}\{\omega \in \Omega: \delta(\omega) =1\}\cap \{\omega \in \Omega: T(\omega) \leq t\}.$$

Intuitively I was going to say it is true but now I think think that only "$\supseteq$" hold. However I can't seem to prove the other inclusion doesn't hold.

---

This background for this question is for competing risk in statistics but as the question is purely probability theoretical, I found it better to ask the question here. I think the answer has to be no otherwise there would no reason to introduce the "cumulative incidence function".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Y(\omega)<X (\omega)\leq t$ then $X(\omega) \leq t$ but $\delta(\omega)=0$.

For an explicit counter-example consider constant r.v.'s $X=2, Y=1, t=2$.